# Explaining environments in Roboschool Half-Cheetah

Tags: environment, robotics, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have some questions regarding the roboschool Half-Cheetah.

1. I see that the observation space for Half-Cheetah is 26. Can anyone tell me what is each value for?- I only counted 18. (also, some of the values seem to remain 0 for all timesteps)
2. In the half_cheetah.xml under roboschool/mujoco_assets, there is the following comment:

   Cheetah Model

The state space is populated with joints in the order that they are
defined in this file. The actuators also operate on joints.

```
State-Space (name/joint/parameter):
    - rootx     slider      position (m)
    - rootz     slider      position (m)
    - rooty     hinge       angle (rad)
    - bthigh    hinge       angle (rad)
    - bshin     hinge       angle (rad)
    - bfoot     hinge       angle (rad)
    - fthigh    hinge       angle (rad)
    - fshin     hinge       angle (rad)
    - ffoot     hinge       angle (rad)
    - rootx     slider      velocity (m/s)
    - rootz     slider      velocity (m/s)
    - rooty     hinge       angular velocity (rad/s)
    - bthigh    hinge       angular velocity (rad/s)
    - bshin     hinge       angular velocity (rad/s)
    - bfoot     hinge       angular velocity (rad/s)
    - fthigh    hinge       angular velocity (rad/s)
    - fshin     hinge       angular velocity (rad/s)
    - ffoot     hinge       angular velocity (rad/s)


Actuators (name/actuator/parameter):
    - bthigh    hinge       torque (N m)
    - bshin     hinge       torque (N m)
    - bfoot     hinge       torque (N m)
    - fthigh    hinge       torque (N m)
    - fshin     hinge       torque (N m)
    - ffoot     hinge       torque (N m)
```

Could you please confirm to me if the order presented here is the same with the order they appear in the observation matrix? If so, should I take the values that are always 0 into account?

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you got some answers on Github, maybe you can create an answer with your findings so others know: https://github.com/openai/roboschool/issues/142

Comment: Thank you. I have also looked into it. I will add an answer to it.